# setting a observer after saveOrderAction - which event do I choose and how do I locate it?

Tags: event-observer, onepage-checkout, magento-1.4

We use Onepage checkout in Magento 1.4

The file where the work is done is:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

The function is `saveOrderAction()`

I want to perform an action after the order has been saved, but a) I don't see any dispatchEvent call in this function and b) I don't know which event to use or to search for.

I have seen exhaustive event lists for Mage 1.x, but I don't know how to correlate to this method.

I also need to know how to add the <observer> XML and place the function, as I have never done this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can use **sales_order_place_after** event.you need to define below code in your module config.xml.

```
 <global>
     <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <OBSERVER_NAME>
                    <class>MODULE_FRONTNAME/NAME_OF_FILE_IN_MODEL_FOLDER</class>
                    <method>FUNCTION_NAME_FROM_ABOVE_CLASS</method>
                </OBSERVER_NAME>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
     </events>
 </global>
```

If you need to define file under following path:
**app/code/YOUR_CODEPOOL/NAMESPACE/YOUR_MODULE/Model/NAME_OF_FILE_IN_MODEL_FOLDER.php** Like Observer.php

In above file need to create function in observer.php with name which define in  tag of config.xml:

```
<?php
    public function sales_order_afterPlace($observer)
    {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      /*YOUR LOGIC*/
    }
?>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: perfect answer with explanation! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Every single controller has a default generic event that can be used for observers. They follow the following naming convention:

- Before dispatching the action: `<controller_action_predispatch_<module>_<controller>_<action>>`
- After dispatching the action: `<controller_action_postdispatch_<module>_<controller>_<action>>`

In your case, it would be the following event: `<controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>`

Then in order to observer this specific event, you need to add the following code to your `global` tag of your `config.xml` file:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>
            <observers>
                <unique_name_for_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>module/observer</class>
                    <method>postDispatchSaveOrder</method>
                </unique_name_for_observer>
            </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>
```

This is assuming that your models are declared under `module` class name.

Then you need to create the `Model/Observer.php` file which would look like this:

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function postDispatchSaveOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // Get the response
        $post = $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse();
        // Do what you need to do with the response
    }
}
```